# Pdf Viewer refreshes during page index change of gridview on asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I have a gridview on an asp.net page with two link buttons - one for viewing a pdf and one for downloading.   When  you click View a pdf viewer is displayed in a literal control.  This works fine.  But I have paging enabled for my gridview and when I click the paging links the pdf display refreshes, meaning it will reload the last pdf viewed.  I'm guessing it has something to do with postback but can't figure out a solution.

```
<div id="wpaLinks" style="height: 118px;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">                         
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvWPAs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3" CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"  
                        PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" OnPageIndexChanging="gvWPAs_PageIndexChanging">  <%--OnRowDataBound="gvWPAs_RowDataBound"--%>
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="fileDescription" HeaderText="File Description" />
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("relPath") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("relPath") %>' runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4" />
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>


            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the code-behind is....

```
protected void gvWPAs_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvWPAs.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    var ctyID = CountyList.SelectedValue;
    var twnID = TwnList.SelectedValue;
    var rngID = RngList.SelectedValue;

    if (ctyID != "0" & twnID == "0" & rngID == "0") // County only
    {
        dsGetCtyWPAs.SelectParameters["ctyID"].DefaultValue = ctyID;
        DataView dvCtyWpa = (DataView)dsGetCtyWPAs.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        //DataTable dtCtyWpa = dvCtyWpa.ToTable();
        gvWPAs.DataSource = dvCtyWpa;
        gvWPAs.DataBind();
        this.RegisterPostBackControl();
    }

}


protected void View(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pdfIdentifier = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"650px\" height=\"850px\">";
    embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
    embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
    embed += "</object>";
    ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/PdfHandler.ashx?pdfPath="), "WpaFiles/" + pdfIdentifier);

}



protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;        
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);        
    Downloader.Download(fileName, "WpaFiles/" + filePath);
}
```

Comment: when you step thru the code..and you're hitting the second link.. does it first go into the `Page_Load` Event..? if so then you have some AutoPostBack happening or you need to code / check for `If(IsPostBack){}`

Comment: @MethodMan: every postback cause a full page lifecycle to occur. so every postback will raise `Page_Load`, even when using an `UpdatePanel`.  Based on the above code the `UpdatePanel` defaults to `ChildrenAsTriggers="True"` and `UpdateMode="Always"`  so no matter what button you hit, pretty much everything causes a postback.

Comment: he's using an Update Panel @fnostro

Comment: yes - twice - I can see that.  Are you implying a full postback doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code re-displays the pdf is due to the second `UpdatePanel` not being updated/cleared.

While controls embedded in an `UpdatePanel` still cause the full page lifecycle to happen - the nice thing about them is that they only transmit back the changes.  So when you are changing a page in the first `UpdatePanel`, you're not clearing the embed code in the second.  This may or may not desired.

On page change you need to clear the embed code in the second updatepanel and make sure that panel gets updated

Comment: So my only option is too clear the second updatepanel - there's no way maintain the pdf displayed in the Literal when I use paging for the gridview the first updatepanel?

Comment: OK - I see you figured it out - grats :)

Answer (score 0):

I set the UpdateMode to Conditional on UpdatePanel3

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">                     
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then added UpdatePanel3.Update() to....

```
protected void View(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string pdfIdentifier = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
string embed = "<object data=\"{0}{1}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"650px\" height=\"850px\">";
embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{0}{1}&download=1\">here</a>";
embed += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
embed += "</object>";
ltEmbed.Text = string.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/PdfHandler.ashx?pdfPath="), "WpaFiles/" + pdfIdentifier);
UpdatePanel3.Update();
}
```